# how to set a column to be a primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table in mysql database

```
number | username      | friendname   | location
------------------------------------------------------------
1      | Nifa salem    |jack          | 47.117828 -88.545625
2      | Flora         | fred         | 38.898556 -77.037852
3      | Flora         | Nifa salem   | 32.9697 -96.80322
4      | Flora         | Anne         | 29.46786, -98.53506
```

but it says this " This table does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available." 
Now i need to set the number column to be the priamry key column! how can o do it! as i need to edit the data in this table.

Comment: How long does it take to search google?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this when creating the table ...

```
CREATE TABLE `admin` (
  `id` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `friendname` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `locatino` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this not as simple as

```
ALTER TABLE yourTableName
ADD PRIMARY KEY (number);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE TableName ADD PRIMARY KEY(Number);
```